# Adjusting the distance between label and axis in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

The single label of following plot is intersected by the curve. How can I make it a little far from axis and point to axis by a dashed line?

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
minor tick num=1,
axis x line=middle,
axis y line=left,
yticklabels={,},
xticklabels={$s$},
xtick=1,
ytick=\empty,
]
\addplot[blue,domain=0:20] {((x)/(x+1))-0.5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please complete your example to a mwe?

Comment: this might be better done using a `pin`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `append after command` in the `xticklabel style` options to insert drawing commands:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis x line=middle,
axis y line=left,
tickwidth=0pt,
xticklabels={$s$},
xticklabel style={
    yshift=-3ex,
    name=label,
    append after command={(label.north) edge [densely dashed] ++(0,3ex)}},
xtick=1,
ytick=\empty,
]
\addplot[blue,domain=0:20, smooth] {((x)/(x+1))-0.5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Jake. `pgfplots`'s syntax is terrible and cryptic!

Comment: @PHPst: That depends. For most standard applications, the syntax is very straightforward. If you need more customised behaviour, you'll have to dig deeper into TikZ (the `append after command` key has nothing to do with PGFPlots, it's pure TikZ syntax). With great flexibility necessarily comes some complexity. Try doing something like this in Excel...

Comment: You are right. Tiks's syntax is cryptic! ◕‿↼