# Plot f(x,y)=x^2-y^2

Tags: pgfplots

Is it possible to make the coordinates axis all go from -1 to 1 and to make the plot look more like a cube? My code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    title={$f(x,y)=x^2-y^2$}, 
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, small]
    \addplot3[surf, domain=-1.3:1.3] 
    {x^2-y^2};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.style={scale only axis}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    title={$f(x,y)=x^2-y^2$}, 
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, small,
    xmin=-1, xmax=1,
    ymin=-1, ymax=1,
    zmin=-1, zmax=1,
    3d box=complete,
    unit vector ratio*=1 1 1,
    ]
    \addplot3[surf, domain=-1:1] 
    {x^2-y^2};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: and how do i scale the x axis so that the shape of the box becomes a perfect cube?

Comment: @DerrHerr you can add `unit vector ratio*=1 1 1,` into axis options

Comment: and how can i move the Numbers and the x,y?

Comment: @DerrHerr What do you mean? Remove it from axes?

Comment: i would like to put the y numbers more up and right and the z nubers more up and the x,y labels more coloser to the zeros

Comment: @DerrHerr This is the different question, you can find the solution somewhere else in `tex.SE`, for example here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119411/adjusting-the-distance-between-label-and-axis-in-pgfplots